# OpenCV Template Matching - Comparing Results

Tags: c, templates, opencv, matching

Is it possible to compare the resulting images after using cvMatchTemplate? There are two objects in my "haystack". One is of similar scale to the template, and is found by the matcher. The other, larger, object, is however exactly the same as the template, but isn't found because of scale.

I would like to write a loop where the template is scaled and results are collected about each scale attempted. I would then like to take the "strongest" of the match results.

Is it possible to compare the match results? How would I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance!